# Specializing `std::hash` for classes meeting condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have a simple boolean traits class, `MyTrait`. That is, for any type `T`, I can do `MyTrait<T>::value` and get either true or false. I would like to specialize `std::hash` for all types `T` where `MyTrait<T>::value` is true. Is there any way to do this? Some failed attempts:

```
template <class T, typename std::enable_if<
                                MyTrait<T>::value, int
                            >::type = 0>
struct hash<T> {
...
}
```

Failed because:

```
error: default template argument in a class template partial specialization
```

I also tried putting all the partial specialization stuff after hash, but then there is an error message for `T` being in a non-deduced context.

Is there any way to do this? At least one previous question on SO suggests there's not: [Specializing std::hash to derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900707/specializing-stdhash-to-derived-classes).

Either a solution, or a definitive 'No' followed by a brief explanation would be a great answer.

Comment: Since `std::hash` only has a single template argument, the only kind of partial specialization you can do is e.g. `template<typename T> struct hash<unique_ptr<T>> { ... }`. I don't see any way to cause a substitution failure there to disable the specialization.

Comment: However, you can provide a custom hash type to `std::unordered_map` etc., which you are free to equip with a dummy template argument for specializations to use.

Comment: @melak47 Yeah, certainly that is an option, doesn't rank too highly for ease of use though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure it is legal, but with concept of C++20, you might do something like:

```
template <typename T>
concept MyConcept = MyTrait<T>::value;

namespace std
{

    template <MyConcept T>
    struct hash<T>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const T& t) const { /*..*/ }
        // ...
    };

}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cf576bc11d94d54)

Comment: Can you expand on "not sure it is legal"? Which part of this would be illegal?

Comment: Not sure that specialize std via concept is legal.

Answer (score 2):

Given templates in the std namespace may be specialised for any *user defined type* (1)

in order to specialise std::hash for some type T if a trait is true we could naively write something like this (note: does not work):

```
namespace std
{
  template<class T>
    struct hash<std::enable_if_t<IsCustomHashable<T>, T>>
    {
       ...
    };
}
```

it doesn't work of course because

> `23 : error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:`

But even if it did, it would put us at risk of violating (1) above.

Because what if someone simply specialised our IsCustomHashable metafunction so that it returned true for an `int`?

Now we would be specialising std::hash for a non-user-defined type, which is forbidden.

one quick and painless way to do what you want is to derive your std::hash specialisations from a helper base class which defers to a free function:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_set>


// a base class that defers to a free function.
// the free function can be found via ADL and it can be 
// enabled/disabled with enable_if. it's up to you.

template<class T>
  struct impl_hash
  {
    using argument_type = T;
    using result_type = std::size_t;
    result_type operator()(const argument_type& arg) const {
      return hash_code(arg);
    }
  };


// a test class
struct my_hashable
{
  bool operator==(const my_hashable&) const {
    return true;
  }
};

// implement the free function in the same namespace as the argument
// type's definition
std::size_t hash_code(const my_hashable& mh)
{
  // calculate hash here
  return 0;
}

// now defining a hash specialisation becomes easy
// you could even macroify it
namespace std
{
  template<>
    struct hash<my_hashable>
      : impl_hash<my_hashable>
    {
    };
}

// check it compiles
int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<my_hashable> my_set;
  my_set.emplace();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Useful info, thanks. I was aware of the macro approach in broad terms; I was hoping to avoid it for the usual reasons.

Answer (score 1):

They say that all problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.

If you are willing, we can implement Sean Parent's [Runtime Polymorphism](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2017-01-18-runtime-polymorphism/2017-01-18-runtime-polymorphism.pdf) technique, which uses type erasure and a teensy bit of polymorphism to delegate to a free function. We can specialize `std::hash` on the erased type.

Usage looks like this:

```
template<> struct MyTrait<Foo> : std::true_type{};
template<> struct MyTrait<Bar> : std::true_type{};
// ...
Foo a;
Bar b;
Bad c; // MyTrait<Bad>::value is false

std::cout << std::hash<my_hashable>{}(my_hashable{a}) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hash<my_hashable>{}(my_hashable{b}) << std::endl;
// compiler error
//std::cout << std::hash<my_hashable>{}(my_hashable{c}) << std::endl;
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x85tkTKXg9ALhnVQ)

Refer to [Sean's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg) for a deep dive on the approach, but here's the code (with my abbreviated explanation to follow).

First, our type-erasure class that holds a pointer to any `T` for which there is a free function `std::size_t do_hash(const T&)`

```
class my_hashable
{
  public:
  template <class T>
  my_hashable(T& x) : self_(std::make_shared<impl_hashable<T>>(&x))
  {}

  friend std::size_t do_hash(const my_hashable& x)
  {
      return x.self_->hash_();
  }

  private:
  struct base_hashable
  {
    virtual ~base_hashable() = default;
    virtual std::size_t hash_() const = 0;
  }; // base_hashable

  template <class T>
  struct impl_hashable final : base_hashable
  {
    impl_hashable(T* x) : data_(x) { }
    std::size_t hash_() const override
    {
        return do_hash(*data_); // call to free function
    }

    T* data_;
  }; // impl_hashable

 std::shared_ptr<const base_hashable> self_;
};
```

Next, our *only* specialization of `std::hash` on the type-erased class:

```
namespace std
{
  template<>
  struct hash<my_hashable>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const my_hashable& h) const{return do_hash(h);}
  };
}
```

#### How it works:

- `my_hashable` is a non-templated class with no virtual methods (good).
- it's only member is `std::shared_ptr<const base_hashable> self_;` where `base_hashable` is a `private` abstract class that requires that children implement a function `std::size_t _hash() const`
- `impl_hashable` is the workhorse here; a templated class whose instances all derive from `bash_hashable` and they all delegate their `std::size_t hash_() const override` function to a free function that accepts a `const T&`
- when we construct a `my_hashable` with an arbitrary type `T`, we take the address of `T` and construct a `impl_hashable<T>` with that pointer. We hide this `impl_hashable` in a pointer to base class `base_hashable`.
- calling `do_hash(const my_hashable&)` will delegate the call to the appropriate `impl_hashable`s `hash_` function via dynamic dispatch.
- we only need to specialize `std::hash` on `my_hashable` and have it delegate to the `my_hashable`'s `do_hash` friend function.

My approach deviates a bit from Sean's in that the type-erased object doesn't own the `T` we give to it, but rather takes a non-owning pointer to a pre-existing one. This will allow you to construct a (lightweight) `my_hashable` only when you need it.

Now we can define our free function that will only work for types where `MyTrait<T>::value` is `true`:

```
template<class T>
std::size_t do_hash(const T& t)
{
    static_assert(MyTrait<T>::value, "Can only call do_hash for types for which MyTrait is true");
    return std::hash<typename T::data_t>{}(t.data);
}
```

Then, as I showed in the start of this post, we can define our classes and decide which ones satisfy the trait. Here, `T` takes on types of `Foo` and `Bar` (not `my_hashable` since we already delegated to `impl_hashable` which recovers the type we passed in when we constructed the `my_hashable` instance)

Comment: I see that std::hash<my_hashable> can be created wrapping a T, however there still seems to be no std::hash<T>. Does this approach allow for the types which specialize MyTrait to be true to be used directly in something like std::unordered_set, without having to specify a non-default hash type in the set’s template arguments?

Comment: @jtbandes: Unfortunately not. We could create a version of `my_hashable` that owns the underlying `T`, and then we could create a `unordered_set<my_hashable>` for example. I realize the additional level of indirection is not ideal, hence the qualification at the top of my post.

Comment: I am familiar with SP polymorphism, that said, this doesn't answer the question, though I appreciate the effort. This isn't specializing on T meeting a trait, but on some other type. This is critical because the goal of this exercise, really the only reason I can think of to specialize std::hash, is to make std::unordered_map/set<K, (V)>, "just work". I can only use your solution if I make the key type `my_hashable` which has lots and lots of undesirable consequences.

Comment: @NirFriedman: Granted. I agree with you. I lean towards saying that Jarod42's answer is correct despite the fact that the standard doesn't really allow or disallow it. Depending on the trait, it's possible that it is true for a type in the standard library, which may be illegal. Otherwise our hands are kind of tied to either using a macro or type erasure.

Comment: @AndyG Yeah I figure it would be on me to ensure that the trait never evaluates true for a type that I don't control. In this particular example, the trait was inheriting from one of my types so I think that would be safe in that regard.