# Specialization of a template class using enable_if

Tags: c++, c++17, partial-specialization, template-classes

I am trying to partially specialize a template class which belongs to an external library.
The external code is basically as follows.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct;
```

I would like the specializations of `enum` types to be the same.
In C++20, I can achieve this by using concepts.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept enum_concept = std::is_enum_v<T>;

template <enum_concept Enum>
struct MyStruct<Enum> {
    // ...
};
```

However, I am having difficulties doing the same in C++17.
So far, I tried using `enable_if` as a non-type parameter.

```cpp
template <typename Enum, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>, bool> = true>
struct MyStruct<Enum> {
    // ...
};
```

But I get the following error messages.

```
error C2756: 'unnamed-parameter': default template arguments not allowed on a partial specialization
error C2753: 'MyStruct<Enum>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
error C2764: 'unnamed parameter': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'MyStruct<Enum>'
```

If the primary template had another template argument, I could write the following code.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct MyStruct;

template <typename Enum>
struct MyStruct<Enum, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>>> {
    // ...
};
```

Is it possible to partially specialize the template class without modifying the primary template in C++17?

Comment: [Using SFINAE partial specialization without touching the primary template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859772/using-sfinae-partial-specialization-without-touching-the-primary-template)

Answer (score 0):

You could just inherit `MyStruct` from the external struct and do this :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename  T>
struct TheirStruct
{
    int x{42};
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct MyStruct;

template <typename Enum>
struct MyStruct<Enum, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Enum>>> :
    public TheirStruct<Enum>
{
};

enum class MyEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct<MyEnum> mystruct;
    //MyStruct<int> mystruct2; <== will not compile
    std::cout << mystruct.x;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to not modify the primary, which is `template <typename T> struct MyStruct;`

Comment: The primary template is not defined, it is only declared in my case. The library requires specializations of the class to be used in other functions.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Me bad in naming... I renamed MyStruct to TheirStruct (to indicate that TheirStruct is immutable)

Comment: Oh only a declaration would indeed not be enough. Though at some point that must be available somewhere or you wouldn't be able to use it in your code anyway