# Hash an object using its base class' partial template specialization for std::hash

Tags: c++, templates

I have a wrapper class for `std::string` that serves as base class for several others. Instances of the subclasses will be used as keys in `std::unordered_set` so I need to provide a hash function for them. Since the hash is only dependent on the `std::string` stored in the base class, I do not want to write a hash function for every subclass but rather use the one from the wrapper class.

This is how I would like to solve the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

class Wrapper {
public:
  std::string name;
  size_t _hash;
  explicit Wrapper(std::string str) : name(str), _hash(std::hash<std::string>()(name)) {}
  size_t hash() const { return _hash; }
};

class Derived : public Wrapper {};

namespace std {

template <> struct hash<Wrapper> {
  std::size_t operator()(const Wrapper &k) const { return k.hash(); }
};

template <typename T> struct hash<std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Wrapper, T>>> {
  std::size_t operator()(const T &k) const { return k.hash(); }
};

} // namespace std

int main(void) {
  std::unordered_set<Wrapper> m1;
  std::unordered_set<Derived> m2;
}
```

This does not compile of course, since `T` cannot be deduced. Clang says:

```
20:30: error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
20:20: note: non-deducible template parameter 'T'
```

And g++ says:

```
hash_subclass.cpp:21:30: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
 template <typename T> struct hash<std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Wrapper, T>>> {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hash_subclass.cpp:21:30: note:         'T'
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21915740/2504172) solution, but I would like to avoid using a macro. Also, this goes against what I expect from inheritance.

Is there a solution for this? Can a subclass inherit its base class' specialization of `std::hash`?

Also, I'm not 100% sure about my use of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of`. Could you tell me whether this would work assuming `T` could be deduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRC, the problem with `std::enable_if` is that it does not work for classes with a single template parameter. Consequently, you cannot specialize `std::hash` by using `std::enable_if`.

However, you can make your own hasher as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Wrapper, T>>>
struct WrapperHasher {
   std::size_t operator()(const T& k) const { return k.hash(); }
};
```

And then use it as a second template argument of `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::unordered_set<Wrapper, WrapperHasher<Wrapper>> m1;
std::unordered_set<Derived, WrapperHasher<Derived>> m2;
```

---

But in your case, you can define a wrapper much more simply as:

```
struct WrapperHasher {
   std::size_t operator()(const Wrapper& k) const { return k.hash(); }
};
```

And then write:

```
std::unordered_set<Wrapper, WrapperHasher> m1;
std::unordered_set<Derived, WrapperHasher> m2;
```

Comment: Hm.... so there is no way I can use `std::unordered_set<Derived> m1;` without creating a template specialization explicitly for `Derived`? I'm hesitant about polluting the interface by forcing users to carry around the extra hasher.

Comment: @Sebastian _"Forcing users"_ indicates that you are writing some API. In that case, I would definitely prefer to manually specialize `std::hash` for all derived classes. How many such classes you have?

Comment: Four and there will probably not be any more, so it's not that big of deal.